# Dragged object tweened back into original position in actionscript 3

Tags: actionscript-3, flash

I have an object on my stage that can be dragged. On release, it snaps back into its orginal position. I want to be able to tween it back into its original position so that it will look smooth and not choppy.  Here is the code that I have so far:

```
var startPosition:Point;

blockSmallz.addEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_DOWN, dragz);
stage.addEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_UP, dragStopz);

function dragz(e:Event):void {
blockSmallz.startDrag();
startPosition = new Point( blockSmallz.x, blockSmallz.y);
}

function dragStopz(e:Event):void {
blockSmallz.stopDrag();
//set back or tween position

blockSmallz.x = startPosition.x;
blockSmallz.y = startPosition.y;
startPosition = null;

}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need a code based tweening library. I would recommend learning GTween: http://www.gskinner.com/libraries/gtween/

After importing the libary, at the point where you go:

```
blockSmallz.x = startPosition.x;
blockSmallz.y = startPosition.y;
```

You would simply instead insert a line of code to tween it back. Something as simple as:

`GTweener.addTween (blockSmallz, 1, { x:startPosition.x, y:startPosition.y } );`